# Ember: render template as view property

Tags: templates, ember.js

I have a view that I'd like to declare like this in hbs:

```
{{view App.ComponentView title="Text Field" optionsTemplate="textFieldOptions" }}
{{view App.ComponentView title="Static Label" optionsTemplate="statifFieldOptions"}}
```

Then in the view definition I'd like to do the following:

```
App.ComponentView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName="blah",
    attributeBindings:["data-type", "draggable", "title", "rel", "data-trigger", "data-content"],
    optionsTemplate:null,
    "data-content": function() {
        var renderedOptionsTemplate = Em.xxx(this.get("optionsTemplate"));  
        return renderedOptionsTemplate;
    }.property(),
//snip
});
```

What I'm looking for is what I should put in place intead of the Em.xxx call there.  is this possible?  It can be using either a partial or a template or whatever...

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve. What is your use case?

Comment: well, i have a bunch of "ComponentView" controls.  I also have a bootstrap popover view for each one.   Each popover view will have some common components in it (a save / cancel button for example).  Although each one has common components in the popover, each will also have it's own unique content in the popover...

Comment: My thought: Create different templates for each controls, include the common components by `{{render}}` / `{{partial}}` depend on components' need of controller.

Comment: You will not be able to use data binding if you render a template into an attribute like this.